# LLVM: How to add a function and insert a function call within a MachineFunctionPass

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, instrumentation

I am writing a `MachineFunctionPass` to do instrumentation. The goal is to insert a function(say `f`) call after certain x86 instructions. `f` is an additional C function which is not present in the orignal program to be compiled. I compile f to get its assembly and then use `BuildMI` to insert each `MachineInstr`. The resulting program instrumented in this way is too redundant for I expand the body of `f` at every insert point. Is it possible to add a function to the program so that I am able to insert using `call f`. According to the [documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html#the-machinefunctionpass-class), it seems impossible to achieve this in a MachineFunctionPass. Maybe I should implement it in the ModulePass. But how to do that? Could anyone give me any pointer?